# QTreeWidget add same item twice

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I'm trying to make some kind of recursion. If you open `P` then you can open  `P` again or do something else. And here is my problem:
I can't add same item twice.

```
while (*it) {
    if ((*it)->text(0) == item->text(0)){
        (*it)->setText(0,"Add_item");
        (*it)->addChild(item);
    }
}
```

Can I make a loop in `QTree` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another item. It seems you add for the same text the same item object over and over again as child. So making a copy of the item and adding that copy as child should work.